# mysql query not returning expected values

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i am writing a mysql query for the following db structure.

```
Professor (EMP ID,Name,Status,Salary,Age)
Course(Course ID,Course Name,Points)
Works(Course ID,EMP ID,Class ID)
Assumptions:
Each course has only one instructor in each semester
Status can take values from “Full”, “Associate”, and “Assistant”
```

I need to do the following.

Return the names of full professors who ever taught at least two courses IN one Class

```
SELECT p.name
FROM professor p, works w
WHERE p.empid = w.empid
AND p.status = ‘full’
AND w.classid IN (SELECT classid
FROM works
WHERE count(courseid)>1)
```

Return the name(s) of the professor(s) who taught the most number of courses IN Class 10

```
SELECT p.names
FROM professor p, works w
WHERE p.empid =w.empid
AND w.classid IN (SELECT classid
FROM works
WHERE classid = 10
AND coursed = max(coursed))
```

But these queries are returning wrong results. I am new to mysql please help.

Comment: You should read about explicit joins, GROUP BY and aggregates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    COUNT(c.Course_ID) AS TCount
FROM Professor AS P
LEFT JOIN Works AS w ON w.EMP_ID = p.EMP_ID
LEFT JOIN Course AS c ON w.Course_ID = c.Course_ID
GROUP BY p.EMP_ID , c.Course_ID
HAVING TCount > 1
```

Comment: This is for which question i have 2

Comment: @user1844638 Can't you at very least test it and see for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative answer for the first one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.empid, p.name
FROM professor AS p 
JOIN works AS w ON
    p.empid = w.empid
JOIN works w2 ON
    w.empid=w2.empid AND w.classid=w2.classid AND w.courseid<>w2.courseid
```